# Can't print Stack<T> C#

Tags: c#, stack

Hi I have a question about my code. Everything should work without a problem, but when I try to print on the console, the stack gives me the following

input:

4

Output:

System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 [System.UInt64] System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 [System.UInt64] System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 [System.UInt64] System.Collections.Generic.
Stack`1 [System.UInt64]

my question is if i need to add a new library because even with int it gives me the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ConsoleApp29
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack<ulong> nm = new Stack<ulong>();

        ulong p = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for(ulong i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            nm.Push(i);
        }

        foreach(int i in nm)
        {
            Console.Write(nm);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do `Console.Write(i);` because I assume that is what you want to write, not the string respresentation of your Stack

Comment: Thanks, I didn't comply at all

Comment: drop the second loop and let .net do the work for you: `Console.Write(string.Join(", ", nm));`, i.e. join all the stack items into a string (with `", "` delimiter) and print it out

Answer (score 1):

`nm`, which you are printing, is the entire Stack object; you want to be printing `i`, the current element of `nm`.

Comment: yes that's exactly how i want to print i